# java desktop application localization

Tags: java, message-bundle

I just want to create desktop application which have labels in two language. When I press "EN" button load English language labels otherwise Germany.

In web application I have `.property` file, it is possible to use property file in desktop applications.

Answer (score 1):

Just make like this, you need to have a properties file in each language and reload it on ResourceBundle.

```
package test;
Test.java
bundle_de.properties
bundle_en.properties
```

The main code.

```
package test;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test.bundle", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(rb.getString("wololo"));

        rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test.bundle", Locale.GERMAN);
        System.out.println(rb.getString("wololo"));
    }

}
```

Console output:

```
 Wololo in english
 Wololo in german
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use resource bundles for localization. Read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html) end to end